# How to set dynamic index element using ngFor in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, ngfor, angular10

I'd want to handle dynamic attributes in NgFor Angular using an index.

I have a similar set of properties/interfaces.

```
vehicle1_Name,
vehicle2_Name,
vehicle3_Name
vehicle4_Name,
totalVehCount
```

Like this, I'm using a for-loop with **totalVehCount**.

```
numVehicle(n: number): Array<number> {
    return Array(n);
  }

<i class="fa fa-car" *ngFor="let veh of numVehicle(qt.totalVehCount);let indexOfelement=index;"></i>
```

It's working fine however I'd like to dynamically print the title/tooltip like this.

```
<i class="fa fa-car" title="{{qt.vehicle[indexOfelement+1]_Name}}" 
                                *ngFor="let veh of numVehicle(qt.totalVehCount);let indexOfelement=index;"></i>
```

How do I go about it?

e.g. If `totalVehCount = 1` then it should be printed like

```
 <i class="fa fa-car" title="{{qt.vehicle1_Name}}"></i>
```

If totalVehCount = 2 then it should be print like:

```
<i class="fa fa-car" title="{{qt.vehicle1_Name}}"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car" title="{{qt.vehicle2_Name}}"></i>
```

Comment: You can try string interpolation. qh.[``vehicle${Indexofelement+1}_Name``]

Comment: @BekaKalandadze
title="{{qt.[vehicle${indexOfelement+1}_Name]}}"  like this? not working!!

Comment: Sorry. I cannot write correct solution, you need to place backticks infront of vehicle and after the Name - that's a backtick  `

Answer (score 0):

With the current way your data is structured over multiple separate properties you are making it hard to iterate over. I would suggest to get the data (or map it) as an array such as

```
vehicles = [{ name: "Toyota"}, { name: "BMW"}, { name: "Honda"}, { name: "Fiat"}]
```

If you need to keep the original properties intact you could do the following to create the array

```
vehicles = [vehicle1_Name,vehicle2_Name,vehicle3_Name,vehicle4_Name].map(name => { name });
```

Afterwards in the template you can just iterate of the array

```
<ng-container *ngIf="let vehicle of vehicles">
  <i class="fa fa-car" [title]="vehicle.name"></i>
</ng-container>
```

This might not be the exact answer you need. You'll probably need to have the mapping of data different, due to it's dynamic nature (in what way it is dynamic isn't clear in your question). But the main suggestion here is to make the data have a structure which makes it easy for you to work with.